# java DOM XML parser getElementsByTagName() not working

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am following some tutorials to make a XML Parser..

I can't get futher because it says the method getElementsByTagName() is undefined for the type Document.

what did i do wrong?

```
import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class Parser {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        SAXBuilder parser = new SAXBuilder();
        Document doc =  
         parser.build("http://developerlife.com/xmljavatutorial1/AddressBook.xml");


        NodeList listOfPersons = doc.getElementsByTagName("PERSON"); 
        int numberOfPersons = listOfPersons.getLength();

    } catch (Exception e){}


  }
}
```

Comment: please show the xml file

Comment: you're accessing the wrong Document class. Please, import as follow:
import org.w3c.dom.Document

Comment: the link is in the code.. @pd30*

Comment: @ipinyol I tried that aswell, doesnt work.

Answer (score 3):

You first need to take a reference to the root element of your document. Try this:

```
    Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
    NodeList listOfPersons = root.getElementsByTagName("PERSON");
```

Comment: Tried it and it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your Element class is using the DOM, while your Document class is using JDOM2. It's not clear whether your intent is to use DOM or JDOM2, but I doubt that you intended to mix them. Check your import statements.

(If you haven't decided yet, JDOM2 is much preferable.)